# convert string to datatable

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am getting this error
cannot convert string to datatable

The code is

```
dt = CType(Session("result"), DataTable)
```

I am trying to store the session value in dt which is a datatable. The session result contains string values.
Can anyone suggest how to convert the session to datatable and store the session value in the datatable.

Comment: Could you show an example of `Session("result")`?

Comment: Add some code where you are assigning the value to Session("result")

Comment: How does this session store the string values? In a array prehaps?

Comment: Session("result") contains the value of the result from the db,ie. it contains the name of the store and their address.

Comment: But what kind of collection do you use to store the store name and address? before you assign it to the Session("result")
 Maybe you can edit your post and add the part where you assign the Sessions value.

Answer (score 0):

I'll take a guess here:

```
dt.Rows(whichRow)(whichColumn) = Session("result")
```

You need to know which cell in your `DataTable` you want to store your session variable in.